# Inpute & Update record in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, updates, input

I am working on creating a user form to store data in excel & update record, I have 3 requirement to complete my user form design.

1. How can i  create a unique reference number (preferable starting with first 3 character in some textbox followed by incremental number) for each of the record which is getting saved in a excel using userform.
2. Also would like to know how can i retrieve a record and update record in excel using userform.(Preferable by using one or two value)
   In case search result have more then one record to search result option to select required record.
3. I will also be adding 3 drop down box(Segment, Product & Sub Product) in user form. Values which are available under Product should depend on what user have selected Value under Segment & Values which are available under Sub-Product should depend on what user have selected Value under Product

Sample structure of Database i have created in excel

```
Segment         Product     Sub-Product
SEG-1           Prod-1      SubP_1
SEG-1           Prod-1      SubP_2
SEG-2           Prod_2      SubP_3
SEG-2           Prod_2      SubP_4
```

Comment: Seems something more suited to Access rather than Excel. Do you **need** to do this in Excel?

Comment: This is three questions in one. Please split it up into three different questions and show what you have tried and what you need help with.

Comment: would normally recommend using a database for that. there are mechanisms(or/and SQL) for manipulating data. Also there is an auto increment option.

Comment: mehow, cant it be done in excel, Auto incremental is required for creating unique ref for each record in excel no like MUM01, MUM02, MUM03 and so on....